# Generic way to set a proxy server for a JaxRs client

Tags: java-8, jax-rs, resteasy, http-host

I have code where the the webtarget is passed to me from a different library. I do not have access to the code to modify the [ResteasyClient](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.1.0.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/internal/ResteasyClientImpl.html). What I am trying to do is the equivalent of

```
   Client client = new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl()
                   .defaultProxy("127.0.0.1", 9999, "http")
                    .build();
```

I already tried `-Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=9999`

I also tried

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "9999");
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");`
```

Neither one does the equivalent of   `defaultProxy("127.0.0.1", 9999, "http")`

Seems like they might have a solution over [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5576831). I tried signing up to see the solution. But they have no easy way subscribe where I can just punch in my credit card number.

I guess another way to ask this question would be, is there a way, where I can set all instances of org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig have its proxy property set to http://127.0.0.1:9999

**Additional details:**
What I am trying to do is to route http traffic thru a proxy server. I don't want to modify anything at the OS level (traffic shaping stuff). If I use a regular http client in java the parameters `-Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=9999` work. But when using jboss resteasy client those parameters do not work.

Comment: I assume [Configurable.property(String name, Object value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Configurable.html#property-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) is of no use.. ?

Comment: I think the reason the system properties don't work is because of the default [ClientHttpEngine](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-rc-1/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClientBuilder.html#httpEngine(org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ClientHttpEngine)) that is used (which is the [ApacheHttpClient4Engine](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-rc-1/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/engines/ApacheHttpClient4Engine.html)) ....

Comment: ... There is a [URLConnectionEngine](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/0254830b74860b02cc523390e7a892ad302b5ae0/resteasy-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/engines/URLConnectionEngine.java), which uses the  HttpURLConnection (which will make use of the system properties), but you can only change the engine with the client builder.

Comment: One solution (though may not be desirable) would be to remove Resteasy client from the server and add jersey-client to the project. Jersey uses HttURLConnection by default.